# How do I fix gnome-shell-extensions ppa eoan Release does not have a Release file?

Tags: ppa, 19.10, gnome-shell-extension

I'm getting this error:

> Unable to download updates:
>   failed to refresh cache: E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-shell-extensions/ppa/ubuntu eoan Release' does not have a Release file.

[image]

I can see this in:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gnome-shell-extensions-ubuntu-ppa-eoan.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-shell-extensions/ppa/ubuntu eoan main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-shell-extensions/ppa/ubuntu eoan main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-shell-extensions/ppa/ubuntu eoan main
```

But what I do I replace it with? There's no eoan distribution in http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-shell-extensions/ppa/ubuntu/dists/. Does it not exist yet or is it somewhere else?

Comment: You can always make an effort, learn to program, and create your own extension PPA. Generally, this is how you fix things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file)

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer in the [packages section](https://launchpad.net/~gnome-shell-extensions/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+packages).

> This PPA currently publishes packages for Cosmic, Bionic, Artful,
>   Zesty, Yakkety, Xenial, Wily, Vivid, Utopic, Trusty, Saucy, Raring,
>   Quantal, Precise, and Oneiric.

Comment: Understood, but is it EOL, have they not just done it yet, has it been replaced?

Comment: @parsley72 That I don't know.